# Reduce length (remove duplicate parts) of class names

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java so I am not sure how to deal with this, but I have some extremely long class names, like:

```
ItemCheckoutPaymentFragment
ItemCheckoutItemsFragment
ItemCheckoutAddressFragment
ItemCheckoutConfirmationFragment
```

What's the best way to group them, so that I can remove the ItemCheckout part? I know that I can just simply remove that part of the name, but I still want to emphasize that they belong to this `'group'`. Kind of like modules in Ruby.

Comment: you can group in a package named `ItemCheckout`.

Comment: Put the classes inside a `package` called `itemcheckout` and then remove the `ItemCheckout` from the beginning of the classnames.

Answer (score 0):

in your declaration change it to

```
public class ICPaymentFragment
```

then hover over ICPaymentFragment and click rename compilation unit....

make sure you update the class name in your constructor

you can change it to whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

[Packages in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html) are similar to Module in Ruby; both serve similar code-organization roles.

> [Packages] make types easier to find and use, to avoid naming conflicts, and to control access, programmers bundle groups of related types into packages .. A package is a grouping of related types providing access protection and name space management.
>
> ..
>
> You should bundle these classes and the interface in a package for several reasons, including the following:
>
> - You and other programmers can easily determine that these types are related.
> - You and other programmers know where to find types that can provide graphics-related functions.
> - The names of your types won't conflict with the type names in other packages because the package creates a new namespace.
> - You can allow types within the package to have unrestricted access to one another yet still restrict access for types outside the package.

Since the package name itself contains the additional grouping information (e.g. "Item" and/or "Checkout"), it can be removed from the individual types.

(Using [*static* nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) can also be used for grouping, in a sense, but I would not advise doing so in this case and am not sure if Fragments can even be loaded as such.)